# Lists/Libraries left behind after WikiPlus Uninstall

Tags: document-library, powershell, migration

I uninstalled WikiPlus a few months ago, now while migrating to SharePoint 2013 there are libraries referencing the wiki plus templates that were removed when the solutions were retracted and deleted.
Has anyone encountered this? and/or have an easy way to locate the lists/libraries and remove them

An Example -

> MissingFeature True False Database [WSS_Content_Communities] has reference(s) to a missing feature: Id = [a5b72e0e-edbd-458d-8957-16f4653b5060], Name = [WikiPlus Welcome], Description = [WikiPlus Welcome], Install Location = [WikiPlusWelcome].

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the feature from Content Database, and then try upgrading

```
Remove-SPFeatureFromContentDB -ContentDB "WSS_Content_Communities" -FeatureId "a5b72e0e-edbd-458d-8957-16f4653b5060"
```

Comment: PS F:\scripts> Get-SPFeature a5b72e0e-edbd-458d-8957-16f4653b5060
Get-SPFeature : Cannot find a Feature object with Path or Id: a5b72e0e-edbd-458
d-8957-16f4653b5060 in scope Local farm.

Comment: The feature was remove already, there are existing libraries created with a List Template that was part of their solution

Answer (score 0):

Typically developers don't clean up after themselves on feature deactivation as this can lead to a loss of data. Even Microsoft doesn't clean up after themselves when disabling Publishing features. If there are instances of the lists and libraries remaining, they should be deleted from the site(s) and those errors should go away.